# react, x3d custom element and event listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, x3d, x3dom

I am using X3DOM inside my React application to display an external X3D file

```
export class X3DComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.x3dLoaded = this.x3dLoaded.bind(this);
    }

    x3dLoaded(e){
        console.log('inside');
        console.log(e);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <x3d id='x3dElement' is='x3d'>
                    <scene is="x3d">
                        <navigationInfo type='EXAMINE' is='x3d'/>
                        <viewpoint id="viewPoint" is="x3d"
                                   centerOfRotation='0 0 0 '
                                   position="-1.94639 1.79771 -2.89271"
                                   orientation="0.03886 0.99185 0.12133 3.7568"
                                   isActive="true"
                        />
                        <inline id="x3dInline" DEF='x3dInline' nameSpaceName="tanatloc" is="x3d" mapDEFToID="true"
                                url={this.props.fileUrl}/>
                        <loadSensor is='x3d' DEF='InlineLoadSensor' isLoaded={this.x3dLoaded} timeOut='5'>
                            <inline is='x3d' USE='x3dInline' containerField='watchList'/>
                        </loadSensor>
                    </scene>
                </x3d>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I would like to listen to the event emitted by isLoaded in loadSensor.
According to X3D specs

> An isLoaded TRUE event is generated when all of the elements have been loaded. (http://www.web3d.org/documents/specifications/19775-1/V3.3/Part01/components/networking.html#LoadSensor)

How can I do it using React ? This event is emitted after componentDidMount.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `loadSensor` has been implemented in X3DOM, c.f. https://doc.x3dom.org/author/nodes.html. But you can use a 'simple' `onload` event on your inline file:

```
<inline id="x3dInline" DEF='x3dInline' nameSpaceName="tanatloc" is="x3d"
mapDEFToID="true" url={this.props.fileUrl} onload={this.x3dLoaded} />
```

You can also check out https://github.com/x3dom/x3dom/blob/7d8ad13c2d2c17d9fd317e27b9e121379a53407f/test/regression-suite/test/cases/inlineEvents/inlineEvents.html for more examples.

Comment: You are correct, it seems that there is no way to detect when the external file has been loaded and rendered. load only tells you when the file has been loaded but not rendered if I understand correctly ? Also it doesn't solve the issue with React

Comment: So, onload mimics the same behaviour as the loadSensor you mentioned. However there is no real event to check if everything has been rendered. Did you try `onload={this.x3dLoaded}`?

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem as you do. I just write a simple polling in `componentDidMount` to solve this problem.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const poller = () => {
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
            const loaded = document.querySelector('inline').getAttribute('load')

            if (loaded) {
                // do sth
            } else {
                poller()
            }
        }, 500)
    }

    poller()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach... Similar to [@neo_seele's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51608178/2383797), but using rxjs

EDIT added some timeout logic to avoid waiting indefinitely

```
    import { interval, timer } from 'rxjs';
    import { takeUntil, takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';

    //reference to the <inline> element
    const refInline = useRef(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        window.x3dom && window.x3dom.reload();
        //check every 250ms if model is already loaded, when it does, it calls the complete callback
        //however if after 5s it hasn't loaded, it shows an error
        interval(250)
            .pipe(takeUntil(timer(5000)))
            .pipe(takeWhile(()=>!refInline.current.querySelectorAll("Shape").length))
            .subscribe({complete: ()=>{
                if (!refInline.current.querySelectorAll("Shape").length){
                    setError(`Model could not be loaded, please check ${conf.url} format and try again.`);
                } else {
                    // ... my logic
                }
            }});
    }, [...dependencies]);
```